# Showing more events by Mentioning +more in master calendar angular js

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I have implemented Arshaw master calendar in angular js, Lets assume the scenario If I have more than 5 events on the same date, But I dont want to show all the 6 events directly in the date cell of the master calendar, Instead I would like to show only 2 events, And a  link saying that 'more', On clicking on more a popup will be opened showing all the events of that date. For Better understanding I have provided Screen shots of what exactly I want to achieve. Thanks in advance..!!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer, I just set eventLimit Property as follows, And it worked,

```
 eventLimit: true,
 views: {
      month: {
                eventLimit: 1
              }
       },
```